# Why this Scala code doesn't type checked

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, type-systems

I want to write a function to count the size of a binary tree, the function 'size' works fine, but it's too slow. I then write a function called 'size2', however, it's not type checked. Why?

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

def size[A](tree: Tree[A]): Int = tree match {
  case Leaf(_) => 1
  case Branch(l, r) => size(l) + size(r) + 1
}

def size2[A](tree: Tree[A]): Int = {
  trait Timing
  case object First extends Timing
  case object TravelLeft extends Timing
  case object TravelRight extends Timing
  type Stack = List[(Tree[A], Timing)]

  def count(history: Stack, res: Int): Int = history match {
    case Nil => res
    case (Leaf(_), _)::tail => count(tail, res + 1)
    case (b@Branch(l, _), First)::tail =>
      val next = (l, First)::(b, TravelLeft)::tail
      count(next, res)
    case (b@Branch(_, r), TravelLeft)::tail =>
      val next = (r, First)::(b, TravelRight)::tail
      count(next, res)
    case (_, TravelRight)::tail => count(tail, res + 1)
  }
  count(List((tree, First)), 0)
}
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Error:(19, 23) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: test.List[(A$A301.this.Tree[A], Timing)]
    case (Leaf(_), _)::tail => count(tail, res + 1)
                     ^
Error:(21, 34) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: test.List[(A$A301.this.Tree[A], Timing)]
    case (b@Branch(l, _), First)::tail =>
                                ^
Error:(24, 39) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: test.List[(A$A301.this.Tree[A], Timing)]
    case (b@Branch(_, r), TravelLeft)::tail =>
                                     ^
Error:(27, 27) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: test.List[(A$A301.this.Tree[A], Timing)]
    case (_, TravelRight)::tail => count(tail, res + 1)
                         ^
Error:(66, 23) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: test.List[(inst$A$A.Tree[A], Timing)]
    case (Leaf(_), _)::tail => count(tail, res + 1)
                     ^
Error:(68, 34) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: test.List[(inst$A$A.Tree[A], Timing)]
    case (b@Branch(l, _), First)::tail =>
                                ^
Error:(71, 39) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: test.List[(inst$A$A.Tree[A], Timing)]
    case (b@Branch(_, r), TravelLeft)::tail =>
                                     ^
Error:(74, 27) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: test.List[(inst$A$A.Tree[A], Timing)]
    case (_, TravelRight)::tail => count(tail, res + 1)
                         ^
```

Comment: What's your scala version? looks like being compiled for me.

Comment: my scala version is 2.11.7

Comment: I use the same version. I only get the following warning: 
"It would fail on the following input: List(_)
  def count(history: Stack, res: Int): Int = history match {
                                             ^
one warning found"

I copy pasted your code and put your two size methods inside an object.

Comment: I have found the reason, it's because I coded in scala work sheet. But why it doesn't work in scala work sheet? Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you using ScalaIDE (Eclipse) or IntelliJ Scala plugin? I think both of these tools have their own compiler front-end (parser/typechecker, etc) and it may be the case that there is a bug in the way they infer types. Nevertheless, if scalac compiles it, it means your code is correct.

Comment: I am using IDEA with Scala plugin, and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=======================update===========================

Thanks for som-snytt's help. This error raised because I've defined a List in the same package. See the error message, it wants a object of test.List, and the :: object create a List of standard library, which doesn't type checked

========================================================

Ok, thanks for Wickoo's comment. I have tried it again in a Scala file and it works fine. This error only raise in a scala work sheet which I don't know why.

Comment: The obvious question is, do you have a class `test.List` defined somewhere? If you're using compile server, maybe just do a clean rebuild.